# Mysql case when getting another table

Tags: mysql, case

I have got two tables one is log details and another is user name list.
I can get with "`INNER JOIN user_tbl ON log_user_id=user_id`" but also I have got a super user id is exception and this exception user isn't in the user table. I am using this user at the back ground the relation with database is level of this user like as 9999.

How can I show the super user as a name like as "Supervisory"?

Example sql:

Table structures are:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_list_tb` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_pwd` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_owner_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_change_pwd` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_pwd_try` int(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name_UNIQUE` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci;



CREATE TABLE `log_system_tb` (
  `log_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_act_name` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `log_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `log_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `log_message` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49720 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci;




SELECT

log_id,
log_act_name,
log_user_id,
user_name,
log_datetime,
log_message 

from log_system_tb

JOIN user_list_tb
ON (log_user_id=user_id) 

where log_datetime>="2016-04-01 00:00:00" 
 and 
log_datetime<="2016-04-14 00:00:00" 

order by log_id desc limit 1000;
```

Best regards

Mehmet

Comment: please post more detailed

Comment: Plase add your ddl and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a left join because there will not be a row in the user_list that corresponds to the supervisor's logged events. Also please see the case statement below.

```
SELECT

log_id,
log_act_name,
log_user_id,
(case when user_id=9999 then 'Supervisory' ELSE user_name END),
log_datetime,
log_message 

from log_system_tb

LEFT JOIN user_list_tb
ON (log_user_id=user_id) 

where log_datetime>="2016-04-01 00:00:00" 
 and 
log_datetime<="2016-04-14 00:00:00" 

order by log_id desc limit 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you it is worked for me as "(case when log_user_id=9999 then 'Supervisory' ELSE user_name END) as user_name"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

(case when user_id=9999 then 'Supervisory' END)